# ValidatesOnExceptions conflicts with ValidatesOnDataErrors

Tags: wpf, validation

I'm new to WPF, currently learning Validation.
In my simple example I have this Model class:

```
class Book
{
    public int Id
            {
                get { return id; }
                set
                {
                    if (id == value) return;
                    id = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Id));
                }
            }

            public string Title
            {
                get { return title; }
                set
                {
                    if (title == value) return;
                    title = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Title));
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PagesCount));
                }
            }
            public int PagesCount
            {
                get { return pagesCount; }
                set
                {
                    if (pagesCount == value) return;
                    pagesCount = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Title));
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PagesCount));
                }
            }
            public string Color
            {
                get { return color; }
                set
                {
                    if (color == value) return;
                    color = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Color));
                }
            }
}
```

I implemented `IDataErorInfo` and `INotifyDataErorInfo`.
one of my validation rules (authored for testing sake) is that the user can't enter both `SS` in title and `33` in PagesCount, so I added this in the  `INotifyDataErrorInfo`'s indexer:

```
case nameof(Title):
                        if (Title == "N")
                        {
                            AddError(nameof(Title), "Annoying");
                            hasError = true;
                        }
                        if (Title == "SS" && PagesCount == 33)
                        {
                            AddError(nameof(Title), "SS and 33 not compatible");
                            hasError = true;
                        }
                        if (!hasError)
                            ClearErrors(nameof(Title));
                        break;
                    case nameof(PagesCount):
                        if (Title == "SS" && PagesCount == 33)
                        {
                            AddError(nameof(Title), "SS and 33 not compatible");
                            hasError = true;
                        }
                        if (!hasError)
                            ClearErrors(nameof(Title));

                        break;
```

When I enter these values (SS for title and 33 for PagesCount) the red border appear and the error message show in this template:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="8" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=mGrd, Path=(Validation.Errors)}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ErrorContent}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

but when I enter an invalid value for the PagesCount (invalid `int`) like **33e** the error message doesn't disappear from the ListBox, and the border still adorns both textboxes.
I don't know why it doesn't clear the error message from the error template and just keep the red border, so is there a way to do this, and also can I show message for such exceptions (entering **33e** for `int` field)

Comment: Why would the border disappear when you enter an *invalid* value?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `ValidatesOnExceptions` property to true is short for adding the built-in `ExceptionValidationRule` to the binding's `ValidationRules` collection:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Age" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <ExceptionValidationRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

What this does is that it will add a `ValidationError` object to the `Validation.Errors` collection when an exception is thrown when setting the source property (`Age` in this case). And this will cause the `Validation.ErrorTemplate` of the element (`TextBox`) to get shown.

And since you can *never* set an `int` property to "33e" because this is not a valid `int` value, there will indeed be an exception thrown in this case.

Comment: Nothing happens.. is there extra work should be done to the error messages template?

Comment: Also I found some interesting thing: when I typed invalid value neither the the property setter nor the indexer get called!

Comment: This is expected. As I told you, you *cannot* set an int property to anything else than an int value.